# Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method error 'onBitmapFailed(Exception, Drawable)' in 'Target'

Tags: java, android, bitmap, picasso

Hello friends please help me i could not find that what is the problem in my code.

Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method error 'onBitmapFailed(Exception, Drawable)' in 'Target' what is the  problem here ? `

```
public class HeaderFragment extends Fragment implements 

View.OnLayoutChangeListener, Target {

private ImageView mIconImageView;
private ImageView mCoverImageView;
private Picasso mPicasso;
private Drawable mDrawable;
private boolean mIsRunning = false;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_header, 
            container, false);
```

Getting image with picasso

```
    mPicasso = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getPicasso();
    mIconImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.navbar_icon);
    mCoverImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.navbar_cover);

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
        mCoverImageView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
    else
    if (mDrawable != null) showDrawable(mDrawable);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, 
      int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
    if (v.getWidth() > 0 && v.getHeight() > 0 && !mIsRunning) {
        createBitmap();
    }
}

private void createBitmap() {
    if (!Utils.isJellyBeanMR1orLater())
        return;

    mIsRunning = true;

    ArrayList<Comic> comics = 
           Storage.getStorage(getActivity()).listComics();
    if (comics.size() > 0) {
        Comic c = comics.get(new Random().nextInt(comics.size()));
        mPicasso.load(LocalCoverHandler.getComicCoverUri(c)).into(this);
    }
}
```

**....Bitmap Loading Method...**

```
@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
    HalftonerTask task = new HalftonerTask(bitmap);
    task.execute();
}
@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}

@Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}

private void showDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    mCoverImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    mIconImageView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(500).setListener(null);
    mCoverImageView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(500).setListener(null);
}
```

**.....AsyncTask Class......**

```
private class HalftonerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    public HalftonerTask(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
    }

//===========Creating and Scaled Down Bitmap==========//

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        double bw = mBitmap.getWidth();
        double bh = mBitmap.getHeight();
        double vw = mCoverImageView.getWidth();
        double vh = mCoverImageView.getHeight();

        int nbw, nbh, bx, by;
        if (bh/bw > vh/vw) {
            nbw = (int)vw;
            nbh = (int)(bh * (vw / bw));
            bx = 0;
            by = (int)((double)nbh / 2 - vh / 2);
        }
        else {
            nbw = (int)(bw * (vh / bh));
            nbh = (int)vh;
            bx = (int)((double)nbw / 2 - vw / 2);
            by = 0;
        }

        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, nbw, nbh, false);
        Bitmap mutable = scaled.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mutable, bx, by, (int)vw, 
                                                           (int)vh);

        double s = Math.PI/6;
        int a, r, g, b, l, t, f, p;
        int primary = getResources().getColor(R.color.primary);
        for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
                p = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                a = Color.alpha(p);
                r = Color.red(p);
                g = Color.green(p);
                b = Color.blue(p);
                l = (int)(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b);
                t = (int)((Math.cos(s*(x+0.5))*Math.cos(s*(y+0.5))+1)*127);
                f = (l > t) ? primary : Color.argb(a, 0, 0, 0);
                bitmap.setPixel(x, y, f);
            }
        }

        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(getActivity());
        Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap);
        Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, 
                      Element.U8_4(rs));
        script.setRadius(1);
        script.setInput(input);
        script.forEach(output);
        output.copyTo(bitmap);

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), bitmap);
            showDrawable(mDrawable);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
}`
```

Comment: Just override `onBitmapFailed(Exception, Drawable)` .

Comment: Are you using an IDE (Android Studio)? If so, it should offer to fill in the missing methods for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `onBitmapFailed(Exception, Drawable)` method. The one with **2** arguments.